# Can't upgrade my Intel HD 4600 Driver?

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade, intel-graphics

Please help. My graphics driver is at 10.18.14.4251 and the latest version is 15.40.4.64.4256! I tried installing the new version but when the PC restarted it still showed the old version! The reason why I haven't gone back to Win10 was because of blue screens and I found that the Intel graphic card was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem with the Intel drivers. I would recommend manually deleting the old driver, and then installing the new one. You can do it by:

1. Install the newest driver, but don't restart yet
2. Navigate to the **C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository** directory
3. Find a folder starting with **"igdlh64"** (You might have multiple)
4. Delete all **"igdlh64"** folders that were installed on a previous date except for the most recently installed one (You can check this by looking in the "Date Modified" section)
5. After you are done deleting them (It may require an administrator password) reboot your computer
6. You should now have the most recently installed driver!

Hope it helps!